# Is "key" stored twice in Java HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

When a Key-Value pair is added to a HashMap in Java, in order to determine the bucket location  for value object, the hash map implementation uses hashCode of "key" object and applies hashing to it. And finally the key value pair is stored in the bucket. The key object is stored so that in case of collisions the object can be retrieved correctly.

My question is, is "key" object stored twice in HashMap, once as a key and then in the bucket where key -value pair is stored in a Linked List?

Comment: Apart from buckets, there's no other place to store. So, the key is stored only once, that is inside the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

First of all: a `HashMap` and (*anything else* in fact) can only ever store a *reference* to some object you pass into it. So even *if* it were to store two references to the key, the memory requirement for that would be minimal.

Next: the actual *implementation* of `HashMap` is not prescribed by the Java standard, so it may (and will) vary depending on *which* JVM you use.

And finally, looking [at the OpenJDK source code of `HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java), the `Entry` class has exactly one reference to the key (in the aptly names `key` field), so the key is stored only once.

Comment: "depending on which JVM you use" depending on which implementation of the Java run-time library, rather than the JVM itself.

Comment: @Raedwald: true, but *usually* the JVM is bound to the runtime library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

No.  To select the correct bucket, the key is hashed, and then this is used as an index.  No need to store anything here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it does not seem like this would be necessary.  When accessing a bucket in a HashMap, the hash function is applied to the key that is being searched.  It could then compare this key to the key that is stored.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to know exactly how `HashMap` works, then you can lookup the source code. There should be a file named `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory that contains the Java source code of all the classes and interfaces in the standard library.